# Partimage and autocheck problem when restoring Windows XP from image

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, images, disk-cloning

I'm trying to create an image of Windows XP and clone it to several partitions on the same hard drive using Partimage. I seem to be running into a problem when I restore the image onto another partition - when I boot into the OS from the partition I just restored, it brings up this message during the boot sequence: `autochk program not found - skipping autocheck`, and then after this, the OS reboots the PC and the whole process repeats itself in an infinite loop.

After doing some Google search, it is suggested that this loop was caused by the partition being hidden or the *mountmgr.sys* file is missing. I checked my configuration and verified that this was not the case.

I'm just wondering:

- Has anyone else experienced this and is there a solution for it?
- Is this what happens when you try to
  restore the image to a different
  partition on the same hard disk or is
  Partimage itself the problem?
- Should I be trying out a different
  partition cloning software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NTFS partition has a [BIOS Parameter Block](http://thestarman.narod.ru/asm/mbr/NTFSBR.htm) at its start where one field (a DWORD at offset 0x1C, the "Number of Hidden Sectors") says where on the disk it is located.

You must either (a) restore the partition at the exact same sector in the harddisk, or (b) patch this field (writing number in Little-Endian style), if you want to boot from it.

E.g. to state that a partition is loaded at sector 63 (default in XP), use:

```
echo 63 | gawk '{printf("%c%c%c%c",$1,rshift($1,8),rshift($1,16),rshift($1,24))}' | dd bs=1 count=4 seek=28 of=/dev/sda1
```

where `/dev/sda1` is the partition in question.

You can use `fdisk` to view current partitions:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

...
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      321300   192089204    95883952+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       192089210   408998834   108454812+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       409001982   625141759   108069889    5  Extended
/dev/sda4              63      321299      160618+  83  Linux
...

# dd bs=1 count=4 skip=28 if=/dev/sda1 | hd

...
00000000  14 e7 04 00
...
```

In this example I have NTFS partition /dev/sda1 (with Win Vista) at sector 321300 (0x0004e714).

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. A couple of other sources indicates that this field needs to be changed as well. Although I think it is called a Bios Parameter Block and not Boot. It also seems that I need to modify the boot.ini file to point to the correct partition after the restore.

Comment: Indeed it is a Freudian slip; BPB is the BIOS Parameter Block!